# How can I upload user-generated svg to the server?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, svg, server

Having spent three days researching and failing to enable user-generated svg upload to the server, I'm completely stumped.

I've built an HTML and Javascript site for users to create a basic model of a vehicle, by entering dimensions into a form.

Those dimensions are then used to edit each svgs 'x' and 'y' coordinates.

I've had success with converting the nested svg to base64 and then downloading to the users filesystem using a button (although it isn't working on JSFiddle), and also experimented with saving the file to local storage.

The output javascript has proven to work absolutely fine, but I just can't figure out how to get that output onto the server in any way.

I'd like to be able to have a user submit their edited svg to the server, where I can then reference it on another page.

I'm fairly unfamiliar with server side code and practise but so far have tried the common suggestions such as:

```
  $.ajax({
  url: ajaxurl,
  type: 'POST',...
```

as well as various iterations of PHP code to receive the svg.

Here's the (mostly) working Fiddle of my site so far.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jafle20/20arn6ct/3/)

## Edit for better context

This is a very simplified version of the nested svg that I'm trying to export to server

```
<svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="Layer_1">
    <rect id="rect1"/>
    <rect id="rect2"/>
</svg>
```

Export is attached to this button

```
<button id="downloadSVG">Download</button>
```

And then the export script

```
 <script>
                    function downloadSVGAsText() {
                        const svg = document.querySelector('svg');
                        const base64doc = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(svg.outerHTML)));
                        const a = document.createElement('a');
                        const e = new MouseEvent('click');
                        a.download = 'download.svg';
                        a.href = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + base64doc;
                        a.dispatchEvent(e);
                    }

                    const downloadSVG = document.querySelector('#downloadSVG');
                    downloadSVG.addEventListener('click', downloadSVGAsText);

                </script>
```

[Simplified JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jafle20/bkm9eqvt/3/)

What I'm completely lost about is how to post the nested svg to the server, so that users can edit or use it later.

So far I understand that I will need Ajax to pass the Base64 image from javascript to PHP file on the server, then the PHP file will place the image on to the server. I just don't seem to be able to make it work. The main issue is how to get the generated Base64 to PHP. The rest I'm happy to work out.

Comment: Please share more details, like the code you are using. What **exactly** is not working? Is this a JS problem (where you struggle with sending the proper request), or a PHP problem (where you struggle with handling it correctly)? Also, are you sure this problem is really related to SVG itself (as you haven't shared any SVG related code so far)?

Comment: Please put **all** relevant code into your question, not into any external site. Also, please reduce the code to those parts that are causing the problem, and omit all surrounding parts - even if they are part of your application, it might get easier to understand your problem with just the relevant parts

Comment: Sorry, I rarely post questions on here. All fixed hopefully.

Comment: What you are missing is what is running on this server you want to send the data to. It does not just magically appear on the server  and written to disk. You need server side code to do this.

Comment: "The main issue is how to get the generated Base64 to PHP" - what have you tried to achieve that? Are you struggling with sending the request (containing that data), or handling it properly on the server?

Comment: "It does not just magically appear on the server and written to disk. You need server side code to do this."
I'm happy to work out what to do server side. However, with variations on the AJAX code in cavemans post I've been unable to get the AJAX to post the output of the javascript-edited svgs. I'm trying to link the output of downloadSVGAsText() to the AJAX post code.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very general question. I think using AJAX is a good way to go. You should be able to just put the SVG in a POST body:

```js
$.ajax('url',{
    'data': svg.outerHTML,
    'type': 'POST',
    'processData': false,
    'contentType': 'image/svg+xml'
});
```

Then use `$svgString = file_get_contents('php://input');` to get the contents of the body, this saves you a lot of encoding and decoding. The rest is up to you.